# A basic question about repetitive exterior's of a set

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a set in a metric space $X$ and let $B=Ext(Ext(A))$, where $Ext(A)$ denotes the exterior of the set $A$. I know that
$$
A\subseteq B
$$
and that the inclusion may be proper. How to prove that
$$
Ext(Ext(B))=B\ ? 
$$
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ext}{\operatorname{ext}}\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$First prove the general facts that $$\ext(\ext(A))=\int(\cl(A))$$ and $$\cl(\int(\cl(A)))=\cl(A)$$ if you’ve not already done so; in this problem you can then conclude that $\cl(B)=\cl(A)$. (If you find some other way to prove this, that’s fine too.) Then $$\ext(B)=X\setminus\cl(B)=X\setminus\cl(A)=\ext(A)\,,$$ so $\ext(\ext(B))=\ext(\ext(A))=B$.

Comment: Thanks Brian (for now and yesterday).

Comment: @boaz: You’re very welcome.